# What are some good SVN capable GUI diff and merge applications available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, svn

I want to have a SVN capable GUI based diff and merge program in Ubuntu that can compare my version of the source code with that in the SVN server repository. Then I can selectively copy the SVN repository’s code fragments onto my working version. This way I can selectively undo the individual changes that I made in my working version.

For each application, what are the steps to do the task I described?

Comment: I just learned how to do the task with meld: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/meld-list/2008-April/msg00010.html although the actual steps are more complicated than that. Would prefer if somebody else answered my question instead of myself. If anybody expresses interest I can write the answer below.

Comment: Basically the steps are ... Save the shell script from the link above into a file called `~\bin\svn-diff-meld.sh`. Then make the file executable via `chmod +x ~\bin\svn-diff-meld.sh`. Create `~/.bash_aliases` and paste in `alias svndm='svn diff --diff-cmd=~/bin/svn-diff-meld.sh'` but remember to replace tilde `~` with your absolute path because it needs to find the file. Run `~/.bashrc` to update aliases. Now you can run `svndm some_directory/some_file` within your local SVN and the GUI would pop up. Hopefully someone would write this answer and I would accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the shell script from the link 
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/meld-list/2008-April/msg00010.html
into a file called `~/bin/svn-diff-meld.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# SVN Diff Wrapper for Meld
# KOG 2008-02

left="$6"
right="$7"

meld "$left" "$right"
```

Then make the file executable via `chmod +x ~/bin/svn-diff-meld.sh`.

Create `~/.bash_aliases` and paste in

```
alias svndm='svn diff --diff-cmd=~/bin/svn-diff-meld.sh'
```

but remember to replace tilde `~` with your absolute path because it needs to find the file e.g.

```
alias svndm='svn diff --diff-cmd=/home/arbartar/bin/svn-diff-meld.sh'
```

if your username is `arbartar`.

Run `~/.bashrc` to update aliases.

Now you can run `svndm some_directory/some_file` within your local SVN and the GUI would pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the detailed steps, but following are some GUI tools :
[RapidSVN](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/rapidsvn/),  http://rabbitvcs.org/  , SmartSVN. 
If you are using KDE there is also [KDESVN](http://www.smartsvn.com/).